# Need a switching circuit that is closed when Vgs is negative and open when Vgs positive, any ideas please?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, jfet

I need a circuit that will be closed when Vgs is negative and open when Vgs positive. Basically the inverse of Enhancement mode MOSFETs or JFETs.

I appreciate your help with this.

Thank you!

Comment: A P-channel MOSFET?

Answer (score 0):

> Need a switching circuit that is closed when Vgs is negative and open
>   when Vgs positive, any ideas please?

OK

> Basically the inverse of Enhancement mode MOSFETs or JFETs

It's not the inverse of a p channel JFET providing you restrict the gate voltage from pushing too much current into the gate when the control voltage is negative. This can be done with a resistor and diode.

Here's the basic characteristic of a p channel JFET: -

[image]

> I need a circuit that will be closed when Vgs is negative and open
>   when Vgs positive

What constitutes and open-circuit or a closed-circuit in your book may of course be different to what I think so, you need to think about this.

Also how much negative and how much positive is something else that you need to consider.

You might also wish to consider P channel MOSFETs and PNP bipolar transistors all of which turn on the more negative the control voltage is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.My main problem is that I need a solution that turns off when the control voltage becomes more positive.

Comment: @lukecam95 yes, that is what a p channel JFET will do so it isn't really a problem. Maybe you need to think about this a bit more?

Comment: The problem with P channel JFETs are that they only go up to 30-40V. I need to switch between 10V and 230V. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @lukecam95 - Use a relay.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that in your question and I tried to cover as much ground as I could. How about an electromechanical relay driven from a p channel JFET or PNP bipolar transistor. Think about what I'm going to say to you if, after reading this comment, you impose another constraint. Nobody here is a mind reader and I have answered your initial question.